# 60s-70s movie. Man makes a wish he was a rock star. But it does not work out

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

I remember a scene from an old movie... Maybe from the 60s in English, probably filmed in USA or UK. (The music club/bar scene had a 1960s era British music scene vibe, which is why I think it was from the 60s-70s.)

Maybe the man finds a magic lamp or something and gets 3(?) wishes. (But they always go wrong.)

The one I remember, he wished to be a rock star with millions of fans. Poof!! he is on stage singing a smash hit. (Doing very good job, and its a catchy song) The song has a "hook", that makes it popular.

Every 30(?) seconds the song pauses, and the everybody freezes for 2 seconds and then the song continues. Everyone, dancers, band, waiters, bartender, (folks watching it on TV at home?) stops what they are doing and freezes during the pauses in the song.

When the song ends he is mobbed by fans and on top of the world.

Then another singer takes the stage and sings some dreary, slow, monotone song.  (Maybe something like "go away", "leave me alone", "I don't want you", etc.) Everyone is just standing (no more dancing) listening to the singer. He finally ends his song spreading his arms out and saying something  "Take me", or "I'm yours", or "Let's do it".

Now **he** is the rock star and the fans all mob him. Leaving the protagonist. The one who granted him his wish, says something like, "Well, you did not say how long you wanted to be a rock star."

The same thing happens on his other wishes but I don't remember what they were.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Bedazzled (1967)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061391/).

> A hapless loser sells his soul to the Devil in exchange for seven wishes, but has trouble winning over the girl of his dreams. -IMDB.com

The scene with the rock star wish is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1pW7T7MbZQ).

Comment: Yes I think that is the movie I was remembering, Because the second singer was definitely the one I remembered.  (I must be mixing up the protagonist song with another movie that had the "Pausing" during the song. I think it was probably in one of those 60s beach movies.)

Comment: :) I was going to guess this, but my brain was thinking of the remake, where they scrapped the rock star scene.

Comment: "Julia Andrews!"